# Using "excludes" config in Findbugs and Checkstyle plugin in Gradle

Tags: gradle, checkstyle, findbugs

I have the following Gradle build file: https://github.com/markuswustenberg/jsense/blob/a796055f984ec309db3cc0f3e8340cbccac36e4e/jsense-protobuf/build.gradle which includes:

```
checkstyle {
  // TODO The excludes are not working, ignore failures for now
  //excludes '**/org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/**'
  ignoreFailures = true
  showViolations = false
}

findbugs {
  // TODO The excludes are not working, ignore failures for now
  //excludes '**/org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/**'
  ignoreFailures = true
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to exclude auto-generated code in the package org.jsense.serialize.protobuf.gen. I cannot figure out the format of the strings given to the excludes parameter, and the documentation isn't of much help: http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.10/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs:excludes (it just says "The set of exclude patterns.").

So my question is: How should the excludes pattern strings be formatted for both the Findbugs and Checkstyle plugins?

I'm running Gradle 1.10.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**: I got the Checkstyle exclude working with the following:

```
tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
  exclude '**/org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/**'
}
```

However, using the exact same exclude on the Findbugs plugin doesn't work:

```
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
  exclude '**/org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/*'
}
```

**EDIT 2**: The accepted answer works, and so does using an XML file and filtering on that, like so:

```
findbugs {
  excludeFilter = file("$projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Package name="org.jsense.serialize.protobuf.gen"/>
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

**EDIT 3**: This works great, and no XML file is needed:

```
def excludePattern = 'org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/'
def excludePatternAntStyle = '**/' + excludePattern + '*'
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    classes = classes.filter {
        !it.path.contains(excludePattern)
    }
}
tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
    exclude excludePatternAntStyle
}
tasks.withType(Pmd) {
    exclude excludePatternAntStyle
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling this is a bug in the Findbugs plugin. The excludes work fine for both Checkstyle and PMD, and according to documentation, they should have the same format.

Comment: I got it to work with an external exclude file (see https://github.com/markuswustenberg/jsense/blob/45fa6164943d85f6390cb8ad258c2b35cf09b125/jsense-protobuf/build.gradle), so I think it's indeed a bug in the Findbugs gradle plugin. I'll file a bug when I find out how.

Comment: Right, reported here: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/findbugs_task_ignores_excludes_property_set_via_exclude_method

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`SourceTask#exclude` filters source files. However, FindBugs primarily operates on class files, which you'll have to filter as well. Try something like:

```
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    exclude '**/org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/*'
    classes = classes.filter { 
        !it.path.contains(new File("org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/").path) 
    }
}
```

PS: It could be that filtering source files makes no difference (and therefore isn't necessary) in case of FindBugs. (I haven't tried though.)

Comment: Cool, thanks, that works. Which means I perhaps haven't actually found a bug. However, I think it's rather counter-intuitive that the "exclude" works only on sources. That's not what I would expect when using the plugin after reading the documentation, especially when it works as expected with both Checkstyle and PMD. Thoughts?

Comment: Checkstyle and PMD primarily operate on source files, so `SourceTask#exclude` is good enough for them. It would be nice to have a simpler way to filter FindBugs classes, but it's not immediately clear how to do this, especially in a backwards compatible way.

Comment: Regarding your PS: Filtering the source makes absolutely no difference. I guess that method is quite useless, then? Or is there a use case where FindBugs actually checks the source?

Comment: It does use the sources (at least in some cases), but my guess is that the class files determine what's being analyzed.

Answer (score 2):

If someone looking for a modern day solution:
For checkstyle, you can use something like this in build.gradle:

```
checkstyleMain.exclude '**/org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/**'
```

If you want to exclude more than one path
solution 1:

```
checkstyleMain.exclude '**/org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/**'
checkstyleMain.exclude '**/org/example/some/random/path/**'
```

solution 2:

```
checkstyleMain {
    setExcludes(new HashSet(['**/org/jsense/serialize/protobuf/gen/**', '**/org/example/some/random/path/**']))
}
```